# Was this outdoor outlet properly installed?

Tags: electrical

[image: outside outlet before in-use was required][image: outlet is inside the cover]
This receptacle was installed prior to in-use requirements and placed inside the box instead of it being recessed.  This is an aluminum garage (separate from the house) and I am not sure what I should do?

I did purchase an in-use box, but I am not sure in this case since the aluminum is very thin and the outside wall is about 1/2" thick. Should I put the whole 15 amp receptacle in the box or try to recess it. Your advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Larry, aren't you in Houston? How did you get through Harvey? What street are you on?

Answer (score 2):

Lucky you. That installation is grandfathered and you have the old type *that work*.

Today for new work, "in use" covers are mandatory, but those things are a complete disaster.   They are expensive, the seals don't work, they divert water into the junction box, and the door breaks off after the first or second use.  On top of that, they won't even close over most extension cords.  It's a racket.

If you want more water protection, build a little birdhouse around the receptacle with a hinged door and an open bottom for cords to exit.

Just put GFCI protection on the circuit somewhere upstream, and don't worry about it.

Here's the trick with GFCIs.  **Never put one outdoors**, you need a special expensive type if you do.  Every GFCI receptacle has a second set of terminals called `LOAD`.  It is designed to feed additional receptacles, *and it will confer GFCI protection to those receptacles also.*. You add "GFCI protected" stickers to those downstream receptacles.

So you put a regular GFCI *indoors* in the circuit upstream of that receptacle.  Voila, done.

The other reason not to put GFCIs outdoors is that the wires going into a GFCI (to its `LINE` terminals) **do not have GFCI protection**.  If they get wet, they can create a serious shock hazard.  By putting the GFCI safely inside and feeding off `LOAD`, the entire outdoor socket and supply cables are all protected.

Comment: HArper.. thank you .. hate that box and if i change it to in use with the gfci implanted in the bigger in use cover box...correct nothing would be said? Or do i have to recess it? Simply dont know?

Comment: In-use boxes have a hinged, plastic cover with a notch in it that allows the electrical cord to hang out of it.   It does not need to be recessed.  In fact, recessing it would likely create issues of water penetration into the wall cavity.  We used mounting blocks and cut the siding, during siding process, to butt up against the mounting block.

Comment: Thanks James for adding, agreed don't recess it.  @larrypinsky best to use plain sockets outdoors and feed them off the LOAD terminals of a GFCI which is indoors out of the weather.   As far as in-use covers, in my experience they are horrible.

Comment: Harper even though I'm grandfather, it is still required by NEC. Is metal in-use covers any better since you hate the plastic. And i didnt recesss the box in the garage--will replace it. Thank you.

Comment: Grandfathered means you may continue using something which would not be code if you were installing it today.  That applies to almost everything.  I'm not aware of any metal in-use covers.  In-use covers only matter if it rains while you have something plugged in, and even then it doesn't matter if you have GFCI.

Comment: What about weather GFCI resistant receptacle for the outside--which is required by NEC? You still can do what you suggested by wiring it to the load from within the garage. Or can the weather resistant stand alone with just the line side?

Comment: @larrypinsky *It ain't what you don't know.  It's what you know that just ain't so!  -- Mark Twain*   You totally misunderstand the NEC requirement. They do not require a GFCI receptacle outside or anywhere. They require GFCI protection on certain circuits.  Now if you know how GFCI works, a GFCI in one place can protect outlets in other places.  Some people have trouble believing that and can be super stubborn.  Regardless, it is true.  The proof of the pudding is that a pocket GFCI tester will trip the circuit.

Comment: Like your quote. Harper i do understand the use and protection of GFCI. It is that when you use the load connections - those are affected as well. So if you have a regular receptacle outside that is connected to a GFCI load side that will trip as well and that isnt what i want. I like all of my GFCI's to be independent of each other (line only). Yes GFCI can protect others, but if one trips they all trip as well. When i put my GFCI TESTER IN THE WEATHER RESISTANT it didnt trip.

Comment: Sure I get that... Although do you really get trips often enough for that to matter?   What I'm saying is make the inside one a dummy, whose only purpose is protecting the outside outlet.   You can buy deadfront GFCI receptacles with no slots,  but they cost more, so I say use a live-front and don't plug anything into it LOL!